# Error when inserting multiple json string

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

This code will work however it can only can insert one json string to sql db. If the json string are multiple it will insert only one json string, with this error

> usp_insert_schedule has too many arguments specified.

Can someone give me links of tutorial or guide me at least.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//Object Root
public class jObt
{
    public string empid { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

private void insrt_jString()
{
    iScedule isc = new iScedule();

    //sql stored proc
    String Query = iSQL.STORED_PROCEDURE_SCH_ADD;

    //sql class for insert
    iEmp usr = new iEmp(Query);

    string barc =  txtBarCode.Text.Trim(' ');
    string ddate = isc.get_date();

    //http://get w/ barc & ddate as param
    string input = isc.jValue(barc, ddate);
    string input = @"{""empid"":""B14"",""status""}{""empid"":""B15"",""status"":""Morning""}";

    var output = input.Split(new[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(x => "{" + x + "}")
           .ToList();

    foreach (var json in output) 
    {
        jObt ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jObt>(json);
        usr.Insert_Schedule(ob.empid, ob.status);
    }   
}

//Class for Insert_Schedule 
public class iEmp: iCon
{
    public string Query;
    public string ComString { get; protected set; }
    public iEmp(string ComS): base(ComS) 
    {
        this.Query = ComS;
        Comm.Parameters.Clear();
        Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Comm.CommandText = this.ComString;
        Comm.Connection = Conn;
    }

    //SCHEDULE 
    public void Insert_Schedule(string empid, string status) 
    {
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", empid);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
        Comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

STORED PROC

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_insert_schedule] 
@empid [varchar](32), 
@status [varchar](20)
AS
INSERT INTO Schedule(Ctrl_ID, Status)
     VALUES (@empid, @status)
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code of `Insert_Schedule` method and the stored procedure?

Comment: it work when the value of json string is one but two or more it wont :(

Comment: Why are you trying to parse (split, etc.) the JSON string before passing to `Newtonsoft.Json`? Just deserialize to an object (even `dynamic`) and work with the object directly

Comment: Where do you define and initiate `Comm` in `iEmp` class?

Comment: @kaveman because of this {json1} {json2} what i want is insert({json1}); insert({json2);

Comment: @ekad from iCon its a inheritance

Comment: Got it, yes I missed that there was no separating comma between each JSON object

Comment: @kaveman this is the reason why Im having error to many arguments  clear the parameters
    Comm.Parameters.Clear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your loop below

```
foreach (var json in output) 
{
    jObt ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jObt>(json);
    usr.Insert_Schedule(ob.empid, ob.status);
}
```

You're calling `usr.Insert_Schedule` method more than once if the json contains multiple objects. Now let's have a look at the definition of `usr.Insert_Schedule` method below

```
public void Insert_Schedule(string empid, string status) 
{
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", empid);
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When you call `usr.Insert_Schedule` for the second time, you're not clearing the `Parameters` property of `Comm`. Instead you're adding the same parameters again (`@empid` and `@status`), that's why you got the `usp_insert_schedule has too many arguments specified` error. You need to clear the parameters of `Comm` before assigning the next set of parameters like below

```
public void Insert_Schedule(string empid, string status) 
{
    // clear the parameters
    Comm.Parameters.Clear();

    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", empid);
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: yehey it works thanks ekad. I just missed that part :D